# Warning nos ponteiros de pilhas

Tags: c, ponteiro, stack

Estou tentando fazer uma implementação simples de pilha, entretanto aparece a mensage:

> warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
>   -Wincompatible-pointer-types

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este warning aparece tanto na linha 20 como na linha 29. Esses ponteiros são do mesmo tipo (no*) e a implementação funciona corretamente. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Não coloque o código como imagem, adicione-o à pergunta, formatando-o apropriadamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc definiu a sua estrutura Nó como sendo:

```
typedef struct _no {
   int item;
   struct no *prox;
} no;
```

O certo seria:

```
typedef struct no {
   int item;
   struct no *prox;
} no;
```

Sem o *underscore*